# PHP echo adds a new line

Tags: php, tags, line-breaks

Could somebody explain me why the PHP tags are giving me a linebreak?

And also, how can you delete this or stop this from happening, as it messes up my site.

An example I'm using on my site:

```
<?php include('assets/common/theme_header.php'); ?>
```

EDIT:
This doesn't seem to happen when I'm using:

```
<?php ?>
```

It does however seem to happen only when I'm using echo, which I also use on my include.

Example:

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

This still gives me a "linebreak", and it shows like this in Chrome development kit:
[image]

Comment: Please post the source here

Comment: If you leave the include out, does the whitespace appear as well? If not, you need to show the code of that file. The include might just add the new white line.

Comment: @user1909426 Added an example I'm using on my site which makes this happen.

Comment: @user1663544: Define "line break" in this case.  Are we talking whitespace or a `br` tag?  If whitespace, how does it mess up your side?  If a `br`, the `include` alone doesn't do that.  But the file being included might.  We can't tell without seeing the code in that file.  Please show a more complete example including the surrounding code and the resulting client-side source.

Comment: The Chrome inspection tool will show quoted strings and may add a line break.  View the _page source_ to see if the break is really there.

Comment: any whitespace in that include file, e.g. `?>\n\n\n<?php` would cause such things.

Comment: @Marc B, this also occurs on echo "hello"; which doesn't include any whitespace.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, it actually is there. If I delete the line, the new line is gone and nothing seems to be wrong with my design. It starts to fail whenever I use echo in one of my includes or in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation where a php file on the server always echoed a space, then newline and then the actual echo.  Like " \n[someVariable]".  I got rid of it by making sure the php file had no empty lines at the beginning or end of the file.

So no empty line before the `<?php` or after the end `?>`

Perhaps your problem is related.

Comment: Thanks that was it. I used ob_end_clean();
to figure out which file had the empty lines.